# How can I tell from the command line if the server has KVM enabled?

Tags: virtualization, docker, linux-kvm

I am trying to solve a problem of how to run an android emulator inside a Docker container for the purposes of end-to-end testing in CI build.

One solution I have found says that it "requires KVM enabled on the host machine".

I have SSH access to this machine.

How can I find out if KVM is enabled?

All the resources I found involved enabling KVM but I do not want to make any changes, only view the current state of the server.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the simplest check is whether the file `/dev/kvm` exists.

I base this on the github article
[QEMU/KVM on Docker and CoreOS](https://github.com/ianblenke/docker-kvm):

> For the most part, it is fairly easy to run kvm within docker. The
>   only real hiccup is that /dev/kvm (the device node for the kernel
>   hypervisor access) isn't reissued (or permitted) within docker. That
>   means we have to do two things for basic usage:
>
> - Make the device node
> - Execute the docker container with --privileged

You might also be able to use the
[kvm-ok command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/kvm-ok.1.html).
See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/564927)
for the generated output of the command when KVM is present or not.

Comment: I wasn't able to use kvm-ok as it required installing something new. But I do have the directory /dev/kvm so that looks promising. Thanks!